# How to fix SQL Injection problems from Veracode Security Scan

Tags: security, veracode

We are using Veracode to scan coding. The result reported a likely SQL Injection in line 51. The code is as below.

I'd like to know why this is a SQL injection problem and how to fix it if yes.

```
@Override
public CloseableSqlRowSet queryForRowSet(String sql, SqlParameterSource paramSource) throws DataAccessException {
    try {
        conn = getJdbcTemplate().getDataSource().getConnection();
        psc = getPreparedStatementCreator(sql, paramSource);
        ps = psc.createPreparedStatement(conn);
        applyStatementSettings(ps);
        resultSet = ps.executeQuery();     // this is line 51
        return new CloseableResultSetWrappingSqlRowSet(resultSet, this);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        this.release();
        throw translateSqlException(sql, ex);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        this.release();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is a black-box scanner; could you please provide us with the HTTP request the scanner send and the HTTP response returned by the web server. We would need the scanner's attack details to understand this further.

Answer (score 0):

This is a source code scanner. Below is a method to invoke queryForRowSet().
The sql statement is select REGID, REGPREFIX, DESCRIPTION, DATAALIAS, SYSTEMALIAS from REGULATORYINFO where REGPREFIX = :regprefix.

Please see code as below.

private boolean validateProductVersion(ConfigPackage configPackage, ProductConfig productConfig) {

```
    NamedParameterJdbcOperations toosetEnvTemplate = jdbcTemplateUtil.getNamedParamJdbcTemplate(configPackage.getToolsetEnvAlias());

    Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap();
    param.put("regprefix", productConfig.getToolsetProduct().getRegulatorId());
    SqlRowSet rowSet = toosetEnvTemplate.queryForRowSet(
            "select REGID, REGPREFIX, DESCRIPTION, DATAALIAS, SYSTEMALIAS from REGULATORYINFO where REGPREFIX = :regprefix",
            param);
    if (!rowSet.next()){
        return false;
    }

    VersionNumber toolsetMaxVer = VersionNumber.createFromString(productConfig.getToolsetProduct().getMaxVersion());
    VersionNumber toolsetMinVer = VersionNumber.createFromString(productConfig.getToolsetProduct().getMinVersion());

    String productVersion = "";
    Map<String, Object> paramMap = new HashMap();
    paramMap.put("productname", productConfig.getToolsetProduct().getRegulatorId());

    productVersion = toosetEnvTemplate.queryForObject(
            "select PRODUCTVERSION from INSTALLEDPRODUCTVERSIONS where PRODUCTNAME=:productname AND STBSTATUS='A'",paramMap, String.class);

    VersionNumber productVer = VersionNumber.createFromString(productVersion);
    if (!org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.isEmpty(productConfig.getToolsetProduct().getMinVersion()) && productVer.isLower(toolsetMinVer)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.isEmpty(productConfig.getToolsetProduct().getMaxVersion()) && productVer
            .isHigher(toolsetMaxVer)) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```